# Atomic writes with respect to unexpected power offs

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems, posix

I have a ~100KB-long file which is overwritten every few minutes by a single writer with the `operator <<` on a `std::ofstream`. I want to avoid any kind of "partial writing" situations that might be caused by the system being powered off while the file is being flushed to disk. I want to do this in my software as much as the OS/POSIX permits.

My idea was to use an overwrite-by-rename strategy, that is `flush()` all the data to a temporary filename, then rename the temporary filename the final filename.

My question is if this is a good strategy, in the sense that atomicity on renaming is guaranteed by my POSIX OS (e.g. Linux) or do you have any better ideas (which do not involve hardware modifications and possibly no FS flag modifications at kernel/system level)

Comment: Have you taken a look at how RDBMS software handle this case?

Comment: @zaratustra, thanks for reminding me. I do know RDBMS like SQLite can mitigate these problems, and we do use it elsewhere, but for historic and initial bad design reasons, we must use a file now.

Comment: I imagine the transactional/journaled nature of the underlying filesystem will be the largest factor here. But the strategy seems to be good (failing a UPS). You could expand it to a three phase commit; first write to new temp file, rename the old file, rename the new temp file (then optionally, although probably best, to delete the old renamed file).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't trust the atomicity of the rename - and you can't in the case of a crash with non-journaling filesystem - then you could first rename the original file with a temporary name, then rename the new file to the original name, and only then remove the original file, with the temporary name. That way, if a crash occurs, at least one of the three filepaths would not be currently under modification.

Comment: but a crash might occur right after the original name has been renamed to temporary name (but before the new file is renamed to the original one). this will lead me to no final file

Comment: Why cannot I rely on the atomicity of a rename in case of crash?

Comment: @Martin *but a crash might occur right after the original name has been renamed to temporary name (but before the new file is renamed to the original one). this will lead me to no final file*  So?  If you find that state, you know what state you were in when the system went down and it's trivial to recover.

Comment: @Martin. This strategy in this answer allows you to check for the presence of the three files, hence you will be able to deduce, by way of comparisons, if there is a crash, which file would be the latest file and which one is the old file.

Comment: @Martin there are filesystems that have no guarantees for crash resistance. There might be a case when crashing during overwriting rename, neither filepath is in valid state.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's the best way you can achieve. From applications point of view it will act as atomic operation.

However, you still need to have some support in OS, i.e. journal filesystem. As long as you use ext4, reiser, zfs, xfs or any other modern filesystem, this solution will flush the data in correct order to the underlying hardware. With fat/vfat it may not work though.

Comment: To prevent corruption in the event of power failure may actually require hardware support, like an uninterruptible power supply or batteries/capacitors on the storage medium.